# Does black anti-static FR4 PCB affect circuit performance?

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I want to make a PCB using black ESD FR4 substrate, purely for aesthetic reasons.

The circuit function will be analog audio.

I presume this material has a small amount of conductivity in order to suppress static. What conductivity level should I avoid, in order that the circuit performance is not affected?

I can ask the PCB manufacturer the resistivity or conductivity of the material.

Below is a photo of the kind of PCB I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: http://www.quandaplastic.com/ketonolic-esd-fr4-data-sheet.html  Carbon layer adds cost but does not affect performance unless it bleeds between tracks. Then depends on how much , usually >10M

Comment: I guess the epoxy layer between the copper and the substrate has some insulation, but that would be broken by through hole plating.